# Tool or method to locate duplicate web service calls?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-services

Does anyone know of a diagnostic tool or method to locate duplicate web service calls? We are using c# MVC3. It is a fairly big web project with many developers and the UI layer is making multiple calls to the same service methods with the same parameters during page requests/render because people do not realize that the call has already been made.

Answer (score 0):

Using a web debugging tool (e.g. Firebug in FireFox), use the "Script" feature to put a breakpoint on the javascript method which is being called repeatedly. When that breakpoint is triggered you can then use the "Stack" window to work out what is calling it and why.

You can also use the "Net" feature to see the order of HTTP method calls (e.g. GET, POST, PUT etc.). The order in which methods made may also help you in diagnosing the problem.